# Drag a file out of the browser

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Most tutorials on javascript drag and drop explain how to handle file drops into the browser and how to drag data out of the browser. But I have seen almost nothing about draging a *file* out of the browser.

For example, you start a drag on a div element, drop it on the desktop and a file appears there.

What I have found is this: (from [this example](https://output.jsbin.com/cacaxe/quiet))

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', `image/png:Luigi.png:${e.target.href}`);
```

However, as far as I can see, setting using `DownloadURL` this causes errors in chrome, a crash report in edge and doesn't do anything in firefox.

Is there a standard way to download a file through drag and drop, preferably from a url?

Comment: How do you drag a div element? I can understand dragging an image, but may you demonstrate dragging a div using a [mcve]?

Comment: How would this be implemented exactly? When I try the Luigi example, dragging the link to my desktop creates a URL shortcut, it doesn't download the file. I don't understand the use case anyway. You can easily set up elements that'll trigger an actual download when you click them; what is gained by being able to drag files? Organizing your downloaded files might be easier if you can sort them into folders directly, but if I downloaded a bunch of files I wouldn't want to drag them out of my browser individually anyway.

Comment: @ChrisG on a mac dragging the link does nothing. (firefox/chrome - macos 10.15.7)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tested it on Firefox and Win7

Comment: @ChrisG that makes sense.

Comment: @ChrisG I know the Luigi example doesn't work. I've said so in my post. My question is if anyone know how to make something like this work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Draging any html element is trivial and not what this question is about.

Here is an example of drag and drop in javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

That might look like you are draging an image, but if you drop it into notepad, for example, you see that the drag data is really just a text string. I'm looking for a solution to attaching a file as drag data instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem in the example seems to be that Chrome now requires same origin on the DownloadURL.

At least that's what the Firefox developers believe that have had an issue to replicate this feature for 11 years now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570164

Safari doesn't seem to support it either